# How to get JSON response in jQuery.ajax request to an appengine URL?

Tags: javascript, json, google-app-engine, jquery

My URL service hosted at Google App Engine return JSON content type.

The example URL is [this](http://trim-pk.appspot.com/do?url=http://www.google.com), that works perfect in browser. Also validated from http://jsonlint.com.

I am using following jQuery.ajax call to get the response.

```
jQuery.ajax({
type: "get",
url: "http://trim-pk.appspot.com/do?url=http://www.google.com",
dataType: "json",
success: function(response) {
    alert(response);
} 
});
```

What's went wrong? Why I am not getting the response. It's null.

I have tried with `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` and `contentType: "application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1"`, but got 500.

Following is my Firebug output.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) on your AppEngine app?

Comment: No. This thing is new to me. I should see it.

Comment: @TahirAkram Until you do you'll only be able to make an AJAX request from a page loaded from `trim-pk.appspot.com`, the browser will block it otherwise for security.

Comment: @ robertc I added `resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` in my do servlet. And I got JSON response. (with no change in calling javascript code). Good idea about enabling CORS on app engine app.

Comment: Note that '*' doesn't work for most browsers. And also, even CORS doesn't work for some browsers, like IE or Opera

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I am developing a chrome extension. So this work for Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

`:` and `/` are reserved characters in Url and have a special meaning.

To use them in Url parameters, you must ["Url encode"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) them. Browsers do that automatically.

In Javascript you must do this by hand via [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function. This should do the trick:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "http://trim-pk.appspot.com/do?url=" + encodeURIComponent("http://www.google.com"),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    } 
});
```

**Update:** replaced `encodeURI` with `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: I am still getting null response.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to do `"http://trim-pk.appspot.com/do?url=" + encodeURIComponent("http://www.google.com");`?  The `url` parameter needs to be a well formed URL.

Comment: @ robertc There is some progress happened. I did as you said and changed the dataType:"jsonp". And I got this in my firebug: http://i.imgur.com/B3HKK.png

Comment: @TahirAkram If you leave a space between the `@` and the name, the response notifications don't work

Comment: @robertc: You are right. Only part of URI needs to be URL encoded - the paramater values. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "http://trim-pk.appspot.com/do",
    data: {
        url: "http://www.google.com"
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    } 
});
```

Comment: No luck. Is this a problem of cross domain ajax? As I am on localhost and calling remote. Some people suggest that jsonp should be used. Dont have the idea for that. But it's just simple thing where i am stuck.

Comment: Oh, you didn't sayd. If you calling from different domain - you need jsonp (or cors, that much more complicated)

Comment: Who is owner of trim-pk? Can you make it to respond with jsonp isntead?

Comment: @ Igor I developed trim-pk service. Ok I make it to respond to jsonp. I research this thing.